# if-else statements executing twice inside the closure in textFieldShouldReturn function

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `UItextField` called `addUserField` in which a user can enter an email after the user hits enter I am checking if that email exists in my Firebase DB and if it does it must print "OK"\email and if does not then it should print "BAD"\email. However my code below is not doing what its intended to, it is somehow executing the if conditions twice and I am not able to figure out why.

So incase the email exists in the database it is printing:

```
OK xyz@abc.com
BAD xyz@abc.com
```

Incase the email does not exist in the database it is printing:

```
BAD abc@xyz.com
BAD abc@xyz.com
```

Can anybody help me figure out why the if statement is executing twice and how can I make it so that it just print OK if email exists or BAD if it does not.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
        var email: String = ""
        if let userEmail = addUserField.text{
        email = userEmail
        }
        let userRef = ref.child("users");
        userRef.queryOrderedByChild("role").queryEqualToValue("User").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
            snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let username = child.value["email"] as! String
                if (email == username){
                    print ("OK \(email)")
                }
                else {
                    print ("BAD \(email)")
                }
            }
        })
       return true
    }
```

Comment: you're looping through all the children under "Users", so it prints something for every child. You must have two children in that node, so it prints twice

Comment: Oh yes thats correct, didnt even realize that. Thank you so much! I fixed it by putting a return inside the if and the else statement.